# How do I get a dictionary's information when passed as a variable in a function?

Tags: python

I'm looking to get information from a dictionary/list while it's being passed as a variable into a function in Python.

I will explain what I'm trying to do, so it's easier for you to offer suggestions.

I have three directories with information:

```
lloyd = {
    "name": "Lloyd",
    "homework": [90.0, 97.0, 75.0, 92.0],
    "quizzes": [88.0, 40.0, 94.0],
    "tests": [75.0, 90.0]
}
alice = {
    "name": "Alice",
    "homework": [100.0, 92.0, 98.0, 100.0],
    "quizzes": [82.0, 83.0, 91.0],
    "tests": [89.0, 97.0]
}
tyler = {
    "name": "Tyler",
    "homework": [0.0, 87.0, 75.0, 22.0],
    "quizzes": [0.0, 75.0, 78.0],
    "tests": [100.0, 100.0]
}
```

I also have a working function to calculate the average value:

```
def average(numbers):
    total = sum(numbers)
    total = float(total) / len(numbers)
    return total
```

I'm creating a new function that will pull a students array above e.g. alice as the variable, so I can calculate the average of the 'homework' list.

At the moment I have the function below but it's simply outputting the word `alice` and not the values from `'homework'`.

```
def get_average(student):
    homework = average(student['homework'][0])
```

I'm unsure on how this needs to be writen, but I'm sure it's easy once the syntax/method is correct.

Comment: Try printing `student['homework'][0]`. Now print `student['homework']`.

Comment: @juanchopanza thanks for the advice, I've added them changes and got the following message :  "get_average(alice) raised the following error: 'float' object is not iterable."

Comment: Yeah, obviously. Because of what `student['homework'][0]` is.

Comment: @juanchopanza but shouldn't the average function I mentioned output the value correctly? ... How do I get the value outputted?

Comment: No, why should it? homework[0] is a single integer; you can't take an average of a single value.

Comment: 'cmon, this is easy enough to debug given the hints you've been given.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could rewrite your function like this:

```
>>> def get_average(student, typeOfWork):
...     return average(student[typeOfWork])
... 
>>> get_average(lloyd,'homework')
88.5
>>> get_average(lloyd,'tests')
82.5
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can of course use your existing function directly as follows:

```
print average(alice['homework'])
print average(alice['quizzes'])
print average(alice['tests'])
```

Which displays:

```
97.5
85.3333333333
93.0
```

You could also create a function to display these:

```
def get_averages(student):
    print "Averages for:", student['name']

    for work in ['homework', 'quizzes', 'tests']:
        print "  {}: {}".format(work, average(student[work]))

get_averages(alice)
```

Which displays:

```
Averages for: Alice
  homework: 97.5
  quizzes: 85.3333333333
  tests: 93.0
```